# DICOM CTDI Phantom Type Code Sequence Attribute (0018,9346) - Values?

Tags: dicom

I have checked a lot of DICOM Images about **CTDI Phantom Type Code Sequence Attribute (0018,9346)** Values. I found 2000 times the value: **1)**

What do these signs "**1)**" mean?

https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/ct-image/ct-image/00189346

Answer (score 1):

You should probably ask the engineer, who performed the studies, or the technician who had installed the machine an did setup of the worksation.

I could only guess and I would take a shot that this sequence means, that "there was a phantom used during the study".

You need to get used to the fact, that DICOM standard is something like a suggestion, not a requirement. For example, when you get a series where 0008,1030 ("Study Description")  has value "CTChest", you shouldn't assume that this is a CT of the chest, as it could be any type of the examination.

Comment: Currently I found two different manucaturer (0008,0070) and three different hospitals (0008,0080) where (0018,9346) contains "1)"